# How can I check how many times the local HTML document was opened?

Tags: php, html, ajax

So briefly, assume that we have a standalone HTML document file, that is sent to recepient.
Is there any solution (probably with using 3d-party counter services) to check that the document was opened. And it would be better if that action was hidden from user.

As I suppose placing some PHP script on "friendly" server and making AJAX calls to it is useless because of cross-site request. Or am I wrong and this can be fulfilled? Really I'm not the best in it.

Any ideas? Please help, and thank you.
* The simpliest way is the best.

EDIT: notifying "action" should be performed, when user has viewed a certain section of the document. Generally, if some element was clicked

Comment: So you want to send a page on someone else's site to a recipient and check if they've viewed it? If that's what you're after, an email service like MailChimp will be able to help you out.

Comment: @BFDatabaseAdmin  I'll check this out. Thank you. My bad - I didn't mention, that this notifying "action" should be performed, if a certain section of the document was viewed. So, generally, assume if some element was clicked)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual solution is a "web bug". You put a 1-pixel image on the page, whose `src` points to your server. Include a unique ID in the URL, something like:

```
<img src="http://yourserver/images/empty.jpg?id=123456789" height="1" width="1">
```

You can then scan your log to see if the image was accessed, and use the `id` parameter to associate it with a specific recipient. You should disable caching so that every time they open the document they'll have to download the image again.

Comment: If I add an img element dynamically (after some event), the effect should be the same?

Comment: Adding a class with background-image set will do the same?

Comment: @bo. It would probably have to be an inline style, because most mail readers ignore CSS, but that idea would probably work.

Answer (score 0):

I think AJAX calls should work fine using jQuery crossDomain setting

```
$.ajax({
    crossDomain:true,
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://domain.com/ajax.php",
    data: {
        var1: var1,
        var2: var2
    },
    success: function(data){
    }
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: That sounds good. Can this be perforemd without using jQuery?

Comment: Then you should set your server to support Cross-Origin Resource Sharing and make a HTTP request using simple JS

Comment: @bo. Use normal `XMLHttpRequest`. jQuery is just a convenience library that makes code shorter.